# Ignore null (empty) value mysql SELECT AVG

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php table which counts the AVG from mysql table. 
My problem is that when i have a null value(empty field) on my database table, it's counted like 0 value so the avg result will be wrong.
For example, i have this on my table:

```
userID   question1     

 1         NULL    
 2          7
```

When i make a `SELECT AVG(question1)from table` i get: `3,5` as result(it takes 0 and 7 as values) and that's wrong because user 1 didn't answer for `question1` yet, I want to ignore the null value to get AVG result = 7 (taking only 7 for value).
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to filter the SQL query to only select where the value is not null

```
SELECT AVG(question1) FROM ... WHERE question1 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: No worries, overcomes the best of us.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT AVG(question1)
FROM table 
WHERE 
   question1 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the query:

```
WHERE question1 IS NOT NULL
```